# Avoid reordering and grouping duplicate x-values ggplot (geom_point)

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics

I'm trying to plot the following data frame with ggplot. This data frame has an ordered summary of top10 scores from 13 separate clusters (10x13 = 130 total observations)

```
                    Cell.Type            Score
1                  GN_Thio_PC 2677.80617009519
2                  GN_UrAc_PC 2637.41032364779
3                Mo_6C+II-_Bl 2556.92913594902
4                GN_Arth_SynF 2391.45433001888
5                Mo_6C+II+_Bl 2315.52547519278
6                       GN_Bl 2304.98201202492
7       MF_Thio5_II-480int_PC 2285.71825571867
8       MF_Thio5_II+480int_PC 2248.11270401521
9                    MF_RP_Sp 2224.65822294734
10                      GN_BM 2069.57828218951
11                  T_8Mem_Sp 3650.92933141558
12                 NK_b2m-_Sp 3623.07526981183
13               NK_DAP10-_Sp 3568.82957776803
14              T_8Nve_Sp_OT1 3535.57114525684
15  T_8Mem_Sp_OT1_d100_LisOva 3532.02217747173
16                 NK_49H+_Sp 3519.49779859704
17               NK_DAP12-_Sp  3500.5532642101
18   T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_d10_LisOva 3448.56816636704
19                  NKT_4+_Lv 3445.33162798595
20                  T_8Nve_LN 3442.41228249856
21                   DC_8+_Th 1384.56532273906
22                  DC_8+_SLN 1333.48389922898
23                   DC_8-_Th 1329.54597466529
24             DC_103+11b-_Lu  1293.2048614532
25                    B_GC_Sp 1291.13567921318
26                  DC_8+_MLN 1266.18747131352
27                DC_8+_Sp_ST 1251.44702553637
28                  SC_MEP_BM  1229.9373063931
29             DC_8-4-11b-_Sp 1204.49733058435
30             DC_103+11b-_Lv 1196.79647629317
31                  T_8Mem_Sp 4888.53608836612
32              T_8Nve_Sp_OT1 4844.62387372193
33                  T_8Nve_LN 4803.08591833927
34                 T_8Nve_MLN 4801.60498804064
35                  T_4Nve_LN 4704.34332374882
36                  T_8Nve_PP 4680.54098917638
37                  T_8Nve_Sp 4668.51868809073
38                  T_4Nve_PP  4654.6363768553
39                 T_4Nve_MLN 4644.53632493487
40                 T_4FP3-_Sp 4643.81716614074
41      MF_Thio5_II-480int_PC 2104.44279848771
42       MF_Thio5_II-480hi_PC 2051.91548567208
43                MF_PPAR-_Lu 1971.01987723135
44      MF_Thio5_II+480int_PC  1968.1818651747
45                      MF_Lu 1941.36173402858
46             MF_II-480hi_PC 1821.13874693704
47       MF_Thio5_II+480lo_PC 1787.05712946341
48                 GN_Thio_PC  1728.7523034795
49           MF_Microglia_CNS  1711.6599582643
50             MF_II+480lo_PC 1711.26332938833
51               Mo_6C+II-_Bl 2962.12603781126
52               Mo_6C-II-_Bl 2758.18375042302
53             Mo_6C-IIint_Bl 2638.16680094079
54                      GN_Bl 2620.07541962536
55                 GN_UrAc_PC  2537.2896087047
56               Mo_6C+II+_Bl 2435.36956544536
57                      GN_BM 2387.13935841906
58                 GN_Thio_PC 2337.29884997719
59                 GN_Arth_BM  2311.2451915426
60               GN_Arth_SynF   2128.725307006
61  T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_48hr_LisOva 3285.38489328741
62  T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_24hr_LisOva 3069.01874851731
63                  T_8Mem_Sp 3022.56013472619
64                   T_ISP_Th 2983.45678085374
65  T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_12hr_LisOva 2964.79056150505
66    T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_d5_VSVOva 2950.29516615634
67              T_8Nve_Sp_OT1  2893.7887214778
68    T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_d6_LisOva 2891.41381948125
69       Tgd_vg3+24alo_e17_Th 2875.40895460188
70                T_8SP24-_Th 2858.05344865649
71      MF_Thio5_II-480int_PC 2783.70950776927
72       MF_Thio5_II-480hi_PC 2737.88858084566
73      MF_Thio5_II+480int_PC 2708.73493567958
74             MF_II-480hi_PC 2377.99196863673
75                   MF_RP_Sp 2281.78751440853
76           MF_Microglia_CNS    2145.29897799
77                MF_PPAR-_Lu 2089.46703313723
78                      Fi_Sk 2077.00426240616
79             MF_II+480lo_PC 2070.33177217184
80       MF_Thio5_II+480lo_PC 2049.00134439134
81                 GN_Thio_PC 3158.65427762739
82                 GN_UrAc_PC 2993.45396316058
83               Mo_6C+II-_Bl 2807.36027869234
84               GN_Arth_SynF 2783.56931762011
85                      GN_Bl 2666.31559591767
86               Mo_6C+II+_Bl  2472.0977029947
87                      GN_BM 2422.62741443588
88               Mo_6C-II-_Bl 2309.43925461481
89             Mo_6C-IIint_Bl  2238.0777055497
90                 GN_Arth_BM 2215.70702972594
91               GN_Arth_SynF  3027.3451404511
92                 GN_Thio_PC 2939.74912223882
93                 GN_UrAc_PC 2694.04395500259
94       MF_Thio5_II-480hi_PC 2507.39045396954
95                      GN_Bl 2407.18406139123
96      MF_Thio5_II-480int_PC 2380.65584862485
97                      Fi_Sk 2211.83581518875
98               Fi_MTS15+_Th 2209.41411415371
99           MF_Microglia_CNS 2149.92996548155
100                  MF_RP_Sp 2111.76895702472
101 T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_48hr_LisOva  4316.4227070348
102                  T_ISP_Th 4280.25335061696
103                 T_DPbl_Th 4102.01504953757
104              preT_DN3B_Th 3910.32665898991
105             preT_DN3-4_Th  3907.5798288054
106                  T_DN4_Th 3840.18882533614
107                 SC_MEP_BM 3780.57141700037
108   T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_d5_VSVOva 3757.01659494412
109      Tgd_vg3+24alo_e17_Th 3685.84648926922
110          Tgd_vg5+24ahi_Th 3616.99224871103
111 DC_IIhilang+103+11blo_SLN 4519.50952669406
112  DC_IIhilang+103-11b+_SLN 4415.97080261725
113 DC_IIhilang-103-11blo_SLN 4170.40873917108
114  DC_IIhilang-103-11b+_SLN 3963.46358118485
115           DC_8-4-11b-_MLN  3631.2974118135
116           DC_8-4-11b+_MLN 3386.67029828899
117           DC_8-4-11b+_SLN 3026.47679955977
118               Ep_MEChi_Th 2844.36034968535
119           DC_8-4-11b-_SLN 2835.94178377956
120                 DC_8+_MLN 2183.62863550565
121             DC_pDC_8+_SLN 3785.05815189249
122              DC_pDC_8+_Sp  3767.7193092587
123             DC_pDC_8+_MLN 3758.58340817543
124              DC_pDC_8-_Sp 3747.60526193027
125                   B_T1_Sp 2325.20093650829
126                   B_T2_Sp 2316.21996448563
127                   B_Fo_Sp 2253.78988549461
128                   B_T3_Sp  2225.2075463753
129                  B_Fo_MLN 2159.05742315915
130                   B_Fo_PC 2142.51258891406
```

to obtain a graph like this (which was generated by using the base graphing functions by using a rather ugly code):

[image]

The problem I'm running into is that ggplot groups and reorders the data instead of keeping the original order. How can I stop this behavior?

On another note, is there a better way of structuring this data frame for it to better work with ggplot? I'd like to visualize the top10 scores of all clusters visually separated but side-by-side (like in the image I attached above). My ultimate goal is making my code scalable so it can work with different numbers of starting `clusters` (i.e. 18 clusters as opposed to 13 clusters here) and `top scores` (ie. top5 as opposed to top10 here) amount just as well with minimal code re-writing.

Comment: how is group encoded in the data?

Comment: It is not hardcoded here. I just know every 10 data points belong to a cluster. I need to come up with an elegant method of coding the clusters in. But I think my question about ggplot is still relevant regardless of the coding of cluster id, right?

Comment: ggplot will want cluster id hard coded. Could just add rep(1:13, each = 10) as a new column

Answer (score 1):

It is a little tricky because you have duplicate labels in the different groups, so the standard advice to convert the x-axis labels to a factor is not quite enough. Here I made a copy of cell.type before merging cell.type and group id, the graph is plotted with with this and then the labels switched. I used facets to show the labels

The graph needs to be quite large to work

```
library("tidyverse")
df2 <- df %>% mutate(id =  rep(1:13, each = 10),
              Cell.Type.label = Cell.Type,
              Cell.Type = paste(Cell.Type, id, sep = "_"),
              Cell.Type = factor(Cell.Type, levels = Cell.Type)) 
df2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Cell.Type, y = Score, colour = as.factor(id))) +
  geom_point(show.legend = FALSE) + 
  facet_wrap(~id, nrow = 1, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = df2$Cell.Type.label) +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(x = 0, units = "pt"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size = 4))
```

data

```
df <- structure(list(Cell.Type = c("GN_Thio_PC", "GN_UrAc_PC", "Mo_6C+II-_Bl", 
"GN_Arth_SynF", "Mo_6C+II+_Bl", "GN_Bl", "MF_Thio5_II-480int_PC", 
"MF_Thio5_II+480int_PC", "MF_RP_Sp", "GN_BM", "T_8Mem_Sp", "NK_b2m-_Sp", 
"NK_DAP10-_Sp", "T_8Nve_Sp_OT1", "T_8Mem_Sp_OT1_d100_LisOva", 
"NK_49H+_Sp", "NK_DAP12-_Sp", "T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_d10_LisOva", "NKT_4+_Lv", 
"T_8Nve_LN", "DC_8+_Th", "DC_8+_SLN", "DC_8-_Th", "DC_103+11b-_Lu", 
"B_GC_Sp", "DC_8+_MLN", "DC_8+_Sp_ST", "SC_MEP_BM", "DC_8-4-11b-_Sp", 
"DC_103+11b-_Lv", "T_8Mem_Sp", "T_8Nve_Sp_OT1", "T_8Nve_LN", 
"T_8Nve_MLN", "T_4Nve_LN", "T_8Nve_PP", "T_8Nve_Sp", "T_4Nve_PP", 
"T_4Nve_MLN", "T_4FP3-_Sp", "MF_Thio5_II-480int_PC", "MF_Thio5_II-480hi_PC", 
"MF_PPAR-_Lu", "MF_Thio5_II+480int_PC", "MF_Lu", "MF_II-480hi_PC", 
"MF_Thio5_II+480lo_PC", "GN_Thio_PC", "MF_Microglia_CNS", "MF_II+480lo_PC", 
"Mo_6C+II-_Bl", "Mo_6C-II-_Bl", "Mo_6C-IIint_Bl", "GN_Bl", "GN_UrAc_PC", 
"Mo_6C+II+_Bl", "GN_BM", "GN_Thio_PC", "GN_Arth_BM", "GN_Arth_SynF", 
"T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_48hr_LisOva", "T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_24hr_LisOva", "T_8Mem_Sp", 
"T_ISP_Th", "T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_12hr_LisOva", "T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_d5_VSVOva", 
"T_8Nve_Sp_OT1", "T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_d6_LisOva", "Tgd_vg3+24alo_e17_Th", 
"T_8SP24-_Th", "MF_Thio5_II-480int_PC", "MF_Thio5_II-480hi_PC", 
"MF_Thio5_II+480int_PC", "MF_II-480hi_PC", "MF_RP_Sp", "MF_Microglia_CNS", 
"MF_PPAR-_Lu", "Fi_Sk", "MF_II+480lo_PC", "MF_Thio5_II+480lo_PC", 
"GN_Thio_PC", "GN_UrAc_PC", "Mo_6C+II-_Bl", "GN_Arth_SynF", "GN_Bl", 
"Mo_6C+II+_Bl", "GN_BM", "Mo_6C-II-_Bl", "Mo_6C-IIint_Bl", "GN_Arth_BM", 
"GN_Arth_SynF", "GN_Thio_PC", "GN_UrAc_PC", "MF_Thio5_II-480hi_PC", 
"GN_Bl", "MF_Thio5_II-480int_PC", "Fi_Sk", "Fi_MTS15+_Th", "MF_Microglia_CNS", 
"MF_RP_Sp", "T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_48hr_LisOva", "T_ISP_Th", "T_DPbl_Th", 
"preT_DN3B_Th", "preT_DN3-4_Th", "T_DN4_Th", "SC_MEP_BM", "T_8Eff_Sp_OT1_d5_VSVOva", 
"Tgd_vg3+24alo_e17_Th", "Tgd_vg5+24ahi_Th", "DC_IIhilang+103+11blo_SLN", 
"DC_IIhilang+103-11b+_SLN", "DC_IIhilang-103-11blo_SLN", "DC_IIhilang-103-11b+_SLN", 
"DC_8-4-11b-_MLN", "DC_8-4-11b+_MLN", "DC_8-4-11b+_SLN", "Ep_MEChi_Th", 
"DC_8-4-11b-_SLN", "DC_8+_MLN", "DC_pDC_8+_SLN", "DC_pDC_8+_Sp", 
"DC_pDC_8+_MLN", "DC_pDC_8-_Sp", "B_T1_Sp", "B_T2_Sp", "B_Fo_Sp", 
"B_T3_Sp", "B_Fo_MLN", "B_Fo_PC"), Score = c(2677.80617009519, 
2637.41032364779, 2556.92913594902, 2391.45433001888, 2315.52547519278, 
2304.98201202492, 2285.71825571867, 2248.11270401521, 2224.65822294734, 
2069.57828218951, 3650.92933141558, 3623.07526981183, 3568.82957776803, 
3535.57114525684, 3532.02217747173, 3519.49779859704, 3500.5532642101, 
3448.56816636704, 3445.33162798595, 3442.41228249856, 1384.56532273906, 
1333.48389922898, 1329.54597466529, 1293.2048614532, 1291.13567921318, 
1266.18747131352, 1251.44702553637, 1229.9373063931, 1204.49733058435, 
1196.79647629317, 4888.53608836612, 4844.62387372193, 4803.08591833927, 
4801.60498804064, 4704.34332374882, 4680.54098917638, 4668.51868809073, 
4654.6363768553, 4644.53632493487, 4643.81716614074, 2104.44279848771, 
2051.91548567208, 1971.01987723135, 1968.1818651747, 1941.36173402858, 
1821.13874693704, 1787.05712946341, 1728.7523034795, 1711.6599582643, 
1711.26332938833, 2962.12603781126, 2758.18375042302, 2638.16680094079, 
2620.07541962536, 2537.2896087047, 2435.36956544536, 2387.13935841906, 
2337.29884997719, 2311.2451915426, 2128.725307006, 3285.38489328741, 
3069.01874851731, 3022.56013472619, 2983.45678085374, 2964.79056150505, 
2950.29516615634, 2893.7887214778, 2891.41381948125, 2875.40895460188, 
2858.05344865649, 2783.70950776927, 2737.88858084566, 2708.73493567958, 
2377.99196863673, 2281.78751440853, 2145.29897799, 2089.46703313723, 
2077.00426240616, 2070.33177217184, 2049.00134439134, 3158.65427762739, 
2993.45396316058, 2807.36027869234, 2783.56931762011, 2666.31559591767, 
2472.0977029947, 2422.62741443588, 2309.43925461481, 2238.0777055497, 
2215.70702972594, 3027.3451404511, 2939.74912223882, 2694.04395500259, 
2507.39045396954, 2407.18406139123, 2380.65584862485, 2211.83581518875, 
2209.41411415371, 2149.92996548155, 2111.76895702472, 4316.4227070348, 
4280.25335061696, 4102.01504953757, 3910.32665898991, 3907.5798288054, 
3840.18882533614, 3780.57141700037, 3757.01659494412, 3685.84648926922, 
3616.99224871103, 4519.50952669406, 4415.97080261725, 4170.40873917108, 
3963.46358118485, 3631.2974118135, 3386.67029828899, 3026.47679955977, 
2844.36034968535, 2835.94178377956, 2183.62863550565, 3785.05815189249, 
3767.7193092587, 3758.58340817543, 3747.60526193027, 2325.20093650829, 
2316.21996448563, 2253.78988549461, 2225.2075463753, 2159.05742315915, 
2142.51258891406)), .Names = c("Cell.Type", "Score"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
"47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
"58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", 
"69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", 
"80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", 
"91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", 
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", 
"110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", 
"119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", 
"128", "129", "130"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. I have two main concerns:
1) There are large gaps between plotted points, because, think all the cell populations are plotted with blank data points between informative colorful dots. 
2) This seems to be a rather large block of code. I'm concerned that it will be difficult to write every time I'd like to analyze different data sets from different experiments. 

Do you have a suggestion how to restructure the data frame so, we can shrink down the code needed? Thanks

Comment: first problem should be fixed by edit. Second problem can be solved by assigning plot to object `g` and then running `g %+% df3` or making code into a function